# Problem while running script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am getting error while running [kafka-zookeeper](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/kafka-rpm/blob/master/SOURCES/kafka-zookeeper.init) script.

Command I tried to run the script is

```
 root > /etc/init.d/kafka-zookeeper start
```

#### Problem

```
   2014-01-22 13:05:26,683] FATAL Severe unrecoverable error, exiting (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.12 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap.serialize(FileSnap.java:224)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.save(FileTxnSnapLog.java:257)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.takeSnapshot(ZooKeeperServer.java:259)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:366)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory.startup(NIOServerCnxn.java:160)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:110)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:85)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:108)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:76)
```

#### Note

1. **Permission** is

   ```
   cmd > ls -ld /etc/init.d/kafka-zookeeper 
   -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1470 Jan 22 12:45 /etc/init.d/kafka-zookeeper
   ```
2. `/tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.12` file is present only permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run the following two line and then try to run

```
chmod 755 /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.12
chown root:root /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.12
```